# Basic question: Flat deformation from $F_0$ to $F_2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, deformation-theory

I would like to understand the flat deformation from the quadric surface $F_0=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ to $F_2$.

I think you deform from the smooth quadric $F_0$ to a singular quadric (A$1$ singularity) then resolve to get $F_2$, or something like that. Could someone help by an explicit computation please? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69339/deformations-of-hirzebruch-surfaces-and-toric-action

Comment: You're welcome! But does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!